# performance issue of having multiple grids on SPA

Tags: jquery, performance, internet-explorer, datatables, jquery-select2

I need some design advise here.

I have SPA. Using **jQuery** on page. We have around 30 grids in single page.

Each grid have minimum 5 rows.

This grids have all sort of CRUD operations.

- Create new row in particular grid.
- Inline editing by default.
- Couple of columns are dropdown so that users can select options.
- CheckBoxes at the end of the row, so that user can select rows to delete

In Chrome page loads fast enough.
In Chrome, Creating new row, editing a row, deleting a row works fine.
In Mobile page loads fast enough.
In Mobile, Creating new row, editing a row, deleting a row works fine.

Problem is IE.
IE is taking more than 50sec to load a page. (IE is preferred browser in my work place)
Any operation in IE is issue.
To create a new row in grid, I have to wait 30sec to operation to get complete.   Call to server to save data is fast enough but script on front-end is taking more than usual time to complete the action.

**jquery datatable plugin is use for grid

select2 plugin is used for dropdowns.**

Any suggestions, tips are appreciated.

Comment: So you have a bottleneck in your specific code. How could we possibly help? PS... IE is what.. 1%, 2% market share?

Answer (score 0):

You need to debug your app using IE to find what exact thing taking long time.

Try to use developer tools and check the network tab to see how much time it takes for each files for getting load.

Try to check all your grid and see if there is any specific grid which is taking long time.

You said you are showing the 30 grids on the same page. So it can be possible that IE needs more time to load all the 30 grids than any other latest browsers.

For testing purpose, you can only try to load the few grids which are necessary to load. than you give option to user to choose to load any specific grid may help to improve the performance of your app.

You did not mentioned that which version of IE and Which version of JQuery you are using for making this test. If you are using any older version of IE and JQuery than it is recommended to use the latest version of IE and latest version of JQuery.

You can try to reduce the loading time for each grid may help to improve overall performance of your app.

Without any sample code, we can only provide some general suggestions. If you can provide any sample code than we can try to make a test with it using IE 11 to check the results.

Here are some references to optimize the performance of JS for Internet Explorer.

(1) [How To Improve JavaScript Performance](https://medium.com/beginners-guide-to-mobile-web-development/javascript-performance-371a0ab28cb7)

(2) [how to improve javascript performance in ie](http://dfwinnovationgroup.com/article/10506798.shtml)

(3) [10 Ways to Instantly Increase Your jQuery Performance](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/10-ways-to-instantly-increase-your-jquery-performance--net-5551)